# How To Record and Update the Win, Loss, and Tie History of Rock Paper Scissors Game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a new function that will return the number of each win, lose, and tie results. With each of the user's selection (rock, paper, or scissors), and by clicking the "GO!" button it will update all the counters and logs.

The HTML displays a form of buttons (each for rock paper and scissors options), as well as the executing "GO!" button.

The JS only has one function `play()` and executes the randomizing of the rock, paper, scissors array which will determine what the computer will choose. This function only declares whether each match is a win, loss, or tie, but does not record it (thank you to user @BarMar for helping me with this part):

```js
function play() {

  var types = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  var computer_choice = types[Math.floor(Math.random() * (types.length))];

  document.getElementById("choiceDisplay").innerHTML = computer_choice;

  var user_button = document.querySelector("input[name=choice]:checked");

  if (user_button) {
    var user_choice = user_button.value;
  } else {
    window.alert("You have to choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors first.");
    return;
  }

  if (user_choice == computer_choice) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Tie!";
    return;
  }

  switch (computer_choice) {
    case "Rock":
      if (user_choice == "Paper") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
      }
      break;
    case "Paper":
      if (user_choice == "Scissors") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
      }
      break;
    case "Scissors":
      if (user_choice == "Rock") {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="stuff">
      <h2> Select one: </h2>
      <div class="choices">
        <p> 
          <form>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "Rock" id="Rock"/>Rock
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "Paper" id="Paper"/>Paper
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scissors" id="Scissors"/>Scissors
          </form>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class= "choiceDisplay">
        <div class = "ccc">The Computer Chose:</div>
        <p id= "choiceDisplay"></p>
        <div class = "button"> <button onclick="play()">GO!</button> </div>
        <div class= "label"><p id = "result"></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to record it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a homework problem because I've seen it twice now lol; Anyway one way to do this would be to add displays for the results and update them.

Display

```
   <h4>Wins <span id="wins">0</span></h4>
   <h4>Losses <span id="losses">0</span></h4>
   <h4>Ties <span id="ties">0</span></h4>
```

Update structure

```
var wins = document.getElementById("wins");
wins.innerHTML = parseInt(wins.innerHTML) + 1;
```

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/8qpz9tnx/

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the function, I have declared a global, empty array called "record".

```
var record = [];
```

Every time the user loses, wins or ties, I add the result to the array using the "push" method as follows:

```
record.push("Tie");
```

At the end of of the HTML file, I have added an empty div with the ID of records for easy retrieval.

```
<div id="records"></div>
```

At the end of the `play()` function, I have added a snippet to filter and display the results.

```
document.getElementById("records").innerHTML = "<p>You lost " + record.filter(x => x=="Lose").length + " times.</p><p>You won " + record.filter(x => x=="Win").length + " times.</p><p>It's been a tie " + record.filter(x => x=="Tie").length + " times.</p>";
```

In the code snippet above, you will notice this piece which counts the number of times the person won:

```
record.filter(x => x=="Win").length
```

```js
var record = [];
function play() {
      var types = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
      var computer_choice = types[Math.floor(Math.random() * (types.length))];

      document.getElementById("choiceDisplay").innerHTML = computer_choice;

      var user_button = document.querySelector("input[name=choice]:checked");

      if (user_button) {
        var user_choice = user_button.value;
      } else {
        window.alert("You have to choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors first.");
        return;
      }

      if (user_choice == computer_choice) {
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Tie!";
        record.push("Tie");
      } else {
        switch (computer_choice) {
          case "Rock":
            if (user_choice == "Paper") {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
              record.push("Win");
            } else {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
              record.push("Lose");
            }
            break;
          case "Paper":
            if (user_choice == "Scissors") {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
              record.push("Win");
            } else {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
              record.push("Lose");
            }
            break;
          case "Scissors":
            if (user_choice == "Rock") {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Win!";
              record.push("Win");
            } else {
              document.getElementById("result").textContent = "You Lost.";
              record.push("Lose");
            }
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("records").innerHTML = "<p>You lost " + record.filter(x => x=="Lose").length + " times.</p><p>You won " + record.filter(x => x=="Win").length + " times.</p><p>It's been a tie " + record.filter(x => x=="Tie").length + " times.</p>";
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="stuff">
      <h2> Select one: </h2>
      <div class="choices">
        <p> 
          <form>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "Rock" id="Rock"/>Rock
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value= "Paper" id="Paper"/>Paper
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Scissors" id="Scissors"/>Scissors
          </form>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class= "choiceDisplay">
        <div class = "ccc">The Computer Chose:</div>
        <p id= "choiceDisplay"></p>
        <div class = "button"> <button onclick="play()">GO!</button> </div>
        <div class= "label"><p id = "result"></p></div>
        <div id="records"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue with this is that the record array could easily be manipulated/hacked with dev tools.